# Possible to edit for c++ code in qt creator

Tags: forms, qt

Forgive my ignorance on this, but I'm using QT creator 2.6 and I designed a form in QT designer. Is there no way to edit the c++ source code of the form?

If not, then does that mean when using QT creator I have to either write the code for a window, or use the designer, but I can't do both for the same window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Qt, not QT.

Form is described by `*.ui` file, which is an xml, which you can edit by any text editor (Qt Creator itself forbids to edit it, as I remember).

Usually *.ui file is accompanied with `*.h` and `*.cpp` file, where the form itself and its objects are used.
You can also create form widgets programmatically and place them on the form, that's meaned by Creator.

If you want to create UI via code i suggest you see [Qt Quick and QML](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qml-intro.html).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what do you exactly mean by "edit the c++ source code of the form" but when using designer you still can acces objects from form in code using

```
ui->objName
```

If you want to use your own widget, you can create layout for it in designer and add it later in code(in MainWindow constructor) using something like

```
ui->layoutName->addWidget(yourWidget)
```

Comment: This ultimately led me to the right solution, however I chose the other answer because I think it more accurately answered my question. Thanks